# Python - Convert intergers to floats within a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have an equation in the form of a string, something like this:

```
(20 + 3) / 4
```

I can easily solve this equation by using `eval()`, but it will give me an answer of `5`, not the correct answer of `5.75`.  I know this is because `20`, `3`, and `4` are integers.  So I was wondering, is there any way to just tack a `.0` onto the end of them?  Or is there some other trick I should use to make `eval()` think they are floats?
**Note:** the numbers will not always be integers, so it would be great if the solution could detect if they are integers and treat them accordingly.

**Note #2:** I'm using python 2.7

**Note #3:** I already know that "Python 2 is legacy, Python 3 is the future."

Thanks!

Comment: `I can easily solve this equation by using eval()` maybe you can, but you really shouldn't.

Comment: What should I use, then?

Comment: That would depend surely on context. Why do you need to rely on `eval` here?

Comment: Best to parse the expression and compute the answer from the expression tree.  Using eval means that string could be any string, even "os.call(\"format c:\")" or something similar.  I doubt you can "tack on" a ".0" unless you know either how the string is generated, or you parse the string into an expression anyway.

Comment: @ roganjosh I am writing a very basic program where you enter an equation, and it returns the value.  It seemed to me the using eval was the quickest and cleanest way.

Comment: @ Daniel Brotherston I am aware of the security issues, and have taken steps to prevent things like that.

Comment: `and have taken steps to prevent things like that` There's nothing you can do to prevent that as long as you're using `eval`

Comment: I can limit keyboard input.  Also, I am writing this application for myself, not to distribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/index.html) to parse the string using [`sympy_parser.parse_expr`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html) and then solve/simplify it:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing import sympy_parser
>>> exp = '(20 + 3) / 4'
>>> sympy_parser.parse_expr(exp).round(2)
5.75
```

This would also work for other valid mathematical expressions.